# Building a REST web service

Tags: web-services, rest, get, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am trying to build a simple Web service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>REST_service</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This is my class:

```
package com.service.user;

import javax.ws.rs.*;

@Path("/user/service")
public class UserService 
{
    @PUT
    @Path("/create")
    public void createUser(){

    }

    @GET
    public void getUser(){
        System.out.println("Inside GET");
    }
}
```

I am running it using this request: http://localhost:8080/REST_service/

And it starts fine. But when I go to call the GET request, it doesnt get called.
    http://localhost:8080/REST_service/rest/user/service

I am very confused as to what's going wrong and not able to debug.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to tell jersey to scan your packages for your resource classes so it can register them.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>
            com.service
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
<servlet>
```